# ¿Como dibujar una línea con borde suave en PILLOW de python?

Tags: python, imagen, pillow

Me refiero a que los bordes que dibuja no tienen un cambio gradual, como se ilustra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he intentando, es este código:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), (38,61,78))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon(((0,img.height),(0,0.8*img.height),(0.8*img.width,img.height),(img.width,0),(img.width,img.height)), fill=(42, 185, 157))

img.show()
```

obtengo de cerca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede ver que no hay un cambio gradual en el borde, cambia de un color a otro sin valores intermedios.

Lo que busco lograr es algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`ImageDraw.polygon(xy, fill=None, outline=None)` No ofrece una forma directa de suavizar [documentación](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html)
Intentando con resize según [Is there an antialiasing method for Python PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350645/is-there-an-antialiasing-method-for-python-pil):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), (38,61,78))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon(((0,img.height),(0,0.8*img.height),(0.8*img.width,img.height),(img.width,0),(img.width,img.height)), fill=(42, 185, 157))

width,height=img.size
img = img.resize((width // 2, height // 2), resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = img.resize((width, height), resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)

img.save('out.png')
```

obtengo una imagen borrosa que si vemos en detalle se ve más suave pero más bien borrosa (no se ve igual que el objetivo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Alguien sabe como se puede lograr dibujar estas lineas sin aliasing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución sin cambiar de modulo en [How do I draw an ellipse using pillow with anti-aliasing?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/jfvfy9/how_do_i_draw_an_ellipse_using_pillow_with/)

Lo que propone es empezar con la imagen 'n' veces más grande y luego reducir el tamaño, el código quedaría así:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

mult=10

img = Image.new('RGB', (mult*200, mult*200), (0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon(((0,img.height),(0,0.8*img.height),(0.8*img.width,img.height),(img.width,0),(img.width,img.height)), fill=(255, 255, 255))

width,height=img.size
img = img.resize((width//mult,height//mult), resample=Image.BILINEAR)

img.save('out.png')
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ha tocado multiplicar volver la imagen 10 veces más grande para que el efecto sea notable. y tanteando `BILINEAR` ha quedado mejor que con `ANTIALIAS`

**Nota**
Incrementar la imagen antes de graficar es importante, si se aumenta la escala e inmediatamente se disminuye, el efecto no es el mismo. Se debe aumentar escala dibujar las líneas y luego bajar la escala.